# Display the framerate (FPS) of a CALayer Animation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation, calayer

I've been creating a (fairly) simple CALayer animation on iPad and it's not quite as smooth as I would have liked. In order to see if my attempts at optimisation are working, I'd like to display or output to the console the framerate  ( number of frames a seconds that the system has managed to draw). This feature is commonly found in game engines.

Is this possible with a CALayer animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Instruments for that—instead of Run, go to Profile, and there you can choose OpenGL ES Driver.
[image]

You can watch the WWDC Session 238 - iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animations, it will give you a great understanding of what and how you can improve in your animations.

Comment: What would happen if you had multiple animations running on different threads? Would it show each one separately, or an average of both?

Comment: I'm pretty sure all animations are run on a separate 'animations' thread, but no I was just hypothesising.

Comment: Yes, they do that on their own treads, but you should call them from the main. But what do you mean by 'show each one separately'? As far as i understand, there is only one frame-rate, and it's threadindependent, no?

Comment: Cool, I didn't realise that the frame rate of an animation was thread-independent.